# Issues with reading from excel CSV and writing to another

Tags: python, excel, csv, python-3.x

I have tried a few things and have run into different errors with each attempt. First, I was reading and writing with the `'r'` and `'w'` options, but this lead to resulting csv having blank rows between actual rows when viewed in excel.

So, I figured out that I had to read and write with `'rb'` and `'wb'`. But, now I am getting the error: `_csv.Error iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)`.

Here is my code:

```
def readLines():
    r = csv.reader(open('test.csv', "rb"), dialect="excel")
    return [l for l in r] #causes the error

def writeFile(lines):
    resultFile = open('output.csv', 'wb')
    wr = csv.writer(resultFile, dialect='excel')
    wr.writerows(lines)
```

I do some altering of the `lines` object that requires they be strings. Am I going about this the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that I was not setting the new line attribute.

Here is my updated code that is now working:

```
def readLines():
    r = csv.reader(open('test.csv', "rt", newline=''), dialect="excel")
    return [l for l in r]

def writeFile(lines):
    resultFile = open('output.csv', 'wt', newline='')
    wr = csv.writer(resultFile, dialect='excel')
    wr.writerows(lines)
```

Comment: +1. This is a difference between Python 2 and Python 3. Python 3 must use the text mode when opening the file, because it needs to read the content as Unicode strings. You can also set the encoding if neccessary (if the Excel table contains texts that uses a specific encoding).

Comment: @pepr Thanks for explaining this fix. I was not certain why exactly it worked, but thought it was due to a 3.x vs 2.x difference.

Comment: In Python 2, the string type is actually a serie of bytes. It makes no difference when you read them from file opened in binary or in text mode. This is (mis)used by the csv module. The binary mode is neccessary because it must not stop parsing at a newline (the newline may be part of the string value). In Python 2 the newline character(s) are read as other bytes. The required text mode in Python 3 needs another way to tell that the newlines must not be interpreted -- the `newline=''` (see http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#open). The `str` and `bytes` are distinct types.

Answer (score 1):

If your text has accents or is in some language other than English you probably need to select the correct encoding from [the Python Library standard](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html). Some text editors allow you to know the encoding for a specific file. I found out with TextWrangler. So the correct Python code to read a file with accents (in Spanish), is:

```
import csv
def imp_csv(ruta):
    with open(ruta,'rt', newline='', encoding="mac_roman") as csvfile:
        r = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel')
        for row in r:
            print(','.join(row))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the files in text mode:

```
r = csv.reader(open('test.csv', "rt"), dialect="excel")

resultFile = open('output.csv', 'wt')
```

Comment: I tried that, but it led to having additional lines in my resulting excel file.